# Setting height through css and jquery, css gets precedence

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div where I load some data from the server on click of a list item in a list (myList).
So, my list is on the left side of the page, and when clicked, the result (which is also a list of items rendered as table rows) displays on the right side. The structure is as follows:

Left side of the page:

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Right side of the page:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr><td>data1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data2</td></tr>
    . 
    .
    .
    .
    .
  </table>
</div>
```

The length of the rows is variable as the data is coming from the server.

I needed to make the div 'myDiv' scrollable so I set the styles like the following:

```
#myDiv { overflow: auto; height: 550px; }
```

Now, this div needs to extend all the way to the bottom of the page, so I'm calculating the height and setting it through jquery as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     UpdateDivHeight();

     $(window).resize(function () {

       UpdateDivHeight();

     });

  function UpdateDivHeight() {
       //update div height
       var viewport_ht = $(window).height();
       //other relevant code

       var cal_ht = *; //calculating height here, viewport_ht - blah blah;

       $('#myDiv').height(cal_ht);
       $('#myDiv').css("height", cal_ht + "px !important;");
     }
});
```

The problem I am facing is, though it sets the height correctly when I first come to the page or resize the browser window, when I click on any of the listitems on the same page, it though calculates the height correctly (verified with an alert), gets overwritten with the css style and is set to 550px again.

**EDIT:**

When the data comes in, I am using a For Each block to insert it into the page

```
<div id="myDiv">
 <table class="myTable" style="width:100%">
    @For Each item In Model

      @<tr>
        <td>@item.Name<br />
              <span style="font-size:0.7em;">@item.City, @item.egion</span>
        </td>
      </tr>

    Next
 </table>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to overcome it?

Comment: What is the outermost element of the data coming in off the server?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question completely, but all the list items List Item 1, 2 and so on, and data1, data2 are coming from the server. If it helps, I am using asp.net mvc4 with jquery mobile.

Comment: I'll rephrase: When the data comes in, how do you insert it into the page?

Comment: On the page itself, using For Each block. Updating the question with the code.

Comment: Does your `<div id="myDiv">...</div>` ever get replaced?

Comment: No, it does not get replaced.

Comment: Obviously the data gets replaced with new data as the user clicks on  various list items on the left.

Comment: Something is causing `#myDiv` to lose the inline style applied by `jQuery.css()` when you click one of the list items. If the `div` is not being replaced, then we're not seeing enough of your code to determine where the problem is.

Comment: Why are you even doing it this way? Just set `position:absolute;top:100px;bottom:0` or similar in the CSS. No JavaScript needed.

Comment: Because I need the div to be scrollable. Anyway I solved it. joequincy was right, the click event was responsible for this. Weird behavior though. The li in ul (unordered list) had an "a href", I replaced it with an "onclick" javascript call, and now the styles are getting applied as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Your jQuery CSS application is invalid and is being ignored.

```
   $('#myDiv').css("height", cal_ht + "px !important;");
```

Should be:

```
   $('#myDiv').css("height", cal_ht + "px");
```

Because jQuery applies CSS properties via the style attribute--which is applied *after* stylesheet resources--the `!important` flag is unnecessary.

Removing that leads to jQuery applying a height of `cal_ht + "px;"`. If, for example cal_ht's value was 123, that would mean, jQuery is trying to apply a height of `123px;`, which is not a valid value for height.  However, `123px` is a valid height, so the semi-colon causes the jQuery function to fail.

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H639L/) showing the difference between the two jQuery CSS calls.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I checked and that's not it.

Comment: jQuery applies CSS properties via the style attribute, which is applied after the CSS stylesheet, negating the need for the `!important` flag. The semi-colon causes property to be ignored because `123px;` is not a valid height, whereas `123px` is. Here's proof: http://jsfiddle.net/H639L/

Comment: I totally agree with you but in my case it was something else why the styles were not getting applied.